# Accurate proportions in dplyr contingency table

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have been searching for a way to do this for days and haven't found a programatic solution. I am modeling tidy data in R using Dplyr. I need to be able to create a contingency table that includes proportions. I have followed the solution of several other posts, but with tidy data the calculated proportions are wrong. While I know that I can use prop.table to make these computations, I'd like to stay in Dplyr because of the rest of the work that needs to be done in my workflow. It's a complex survey and variables span many columns throughout, making a tidy approach optimal.

I'll recreate the issue with some simulated data:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0520)

# Create a data frame with three brands
# Simulated survey data for brand familiarity
# A zero means respondent is unfamiliar with brand
# A one means they are familiar with the brand

brands <- data.frame(
  a = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = .3),
  b = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = .6),
  c = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = .55)
)

# Create factors for each

brands$a <- factor(brands$a, labels = c("Unfamiliar", "Familiar"))
brands$b <- factor(brands$b, labels = c("Unfamiliar", "Familiar"))
brands$c <- factor(brands$c, labels = c("Unfamiliar", "Familiar"))

brands %>% 
  select(a:c) %>% 
  gather(brand, score) %>% 
  filter(score == "Familiar") %>% 
  group_by(Brand = brand) %>% 
  summarize(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(Prop = n/sum(n))
```

As you will note, this code calculates the proportion of respondents who were familiar with brand C as 46%, which is incorrect. It should be 57%.

My current workaround is to kludge in the number of rows in the original table (100) in my mutate statement. But I'd love a programatic way to do this, if possible.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You can't `filter`, because the non-matching rows count in the proportion: `brands %>% 
  gather(brand, score) %>% 
  group_by(brand) %>% 
  summarize(n_familiar = sum(score == 'Familiar'),
            prop = n_familiar / n())`

Comment: Thanks, @alistaire If you don't filter, then you aren't really measuring those that are familiar. Your counts will be 100 for each brand, which is incorrect. We want to measure the proportion of people who were familiar to the number of overall respondents (n/100). Dplyr is calculating as (n/300).

Comment: Look at the code; you can calculate the number of `Familiar` values in each group with `sum(score == 'Familiar')`. Unless you want the total to be the total of the `Familiar` values across brands? But that won't give you 57%.

Comment: @alistaire That worked for the tabulation of n (and a handy change I will definitely use in the future!), but the proportions are still wrong because the denominator of prop = ~~300~~ 125. So Brand C has 57 "Familiar" responses, but a proportion of 0.456.

Comment: When I run the code above I get 0.57 for c. Note that it's being calculated in the `summarise` instead of the `mutate`.

Comment: That works! I overlooked that combined summarize step. Many thanks. You saved me a lot of back and forth between base and dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the proportion of each brand that with a `Familiar` value, you can't drop the `Unfamiliar` rows with `filter`, as they contribute to the total count on the bottom. Thus, you have to calculate the number of `Familiar` values in another way, e.g. `sum(score == 'Familiar')`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0520)

brands <- data.frame(
  a = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = .3),
  b = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = .6),
  c = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = .55)
) %>% 
    mutate_all(~factor(.x, labels = c("Unfamiliar", "Familiar")))

brands %>% 
    gather(brand, score) %>% 
    group_by(brand) %>% 
    summarize(n_familiar = sum(score == 'Familiar'), 
              prop = n_familiar / n())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   brand n_familiar  prop
#>   <chr>      <int> <dbl>
#> 1 a             19 0.19 
#> 2 b             49 0.49 
#> 3 c             57 0.570
```

Now `n()` is the number of rows in each group (100) and `n_familiar` is the number of `Familiar` rows.

Answer (score 0):

since you only have two levels, you can use `colMeans`

```
brands%>%
  mutate_all(~as.numeric(.)-1)%>%
  colMeans()
   a    b    c 
0.19 0.49 0.57
```

or even

```
 brands%>%
    summarise_all(~mean(as.numeric(.)-1))
     a    b    c
1 0.19 0.49 0.57
```

or you can directly do

```
brands%>%
    summarise_all(~mean(.=="Familiar"))
     a    b    c
1 0.19 0.49 0.57
```